# How do I go for NLP based on phrases instead of sentences?

Tags: machine-learning, python, nlp, machine-learning-model, stanford-nlp

I have a list of words in this format:

```
chem, chemistry
chemi, chemistry
chm, chemistry
chmstry, chemistry
```

Here, the first column represents the actual word which is in the second column. I need to apply NLP (in python3) so that when the model is trained using this dataset and I give 'chmty' as input, it will give 'chemistry' as output. I don't want string similarity techniques, I want to build an NLP model.

Answer (score 1):

1- use LSTM with character n-gram
x = chem, chemi, chmstry
y = chemistry

2. use fuzzy match with ratio to match the word with base word.

3- use regex, matach the list and get the result

Comment: I think the proposed solutions are quite inefficient. Eg fuzzy matching is irrelevant as the words and their variations are unique and distinct

Answer (score 1):

In NLP parlance what you ask for can be framed as a case of [Lemmatisation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lemmatisation)

There are NLP tools like [spaCy](https://spacy.io/) for Python which support such tasks.

**Beware** that a very simple NLP algorithm for Lemmatisation which can be applied directly to your case is Dictionary Lookup (which is equivalent to a trivial rule-based system). Yes this is an NLP algorithm.